# crystax: sqlite/3/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'openssl/1.0.2h'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to build an Android project with crystax ndk within Android Studio, but I got the following error message:

> Android NDK: /.../crystax-ndk-10.3.2/sources/sqlite/3/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'openssl/1.0.2h' in import path

I searched the `crystax-ndk-10.3.2` folder, and found there is a `sources/openssl/1.0.1p` folder instead of `1.0.2h`.

It looks like sqlite/3 is refering to a 'wrong' version of openssl. But strangely there isn't any reference to `openssl` in `sqlite/3/Android.mk` file at all. And I really have no clue why this is happening as I downloaded a brand new crystax-ndk-10.3.2 copy and didn't alter any bit of it. I googled *crystax sqlite cannot find openssl* and it seems no others are having this problem.

Could anyone please help me find out what's wrong? The following are some details of configurations:

> Gradle version: 2.1.2
>
> Android Studio: 2.2.3
>
> crystax-ndk   : 10.3.2
>
> OS            : macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to Alex, I finally figured out what's going wrong.

Basically, after extracting the CrystaX package, one also needs to build openssl, and copy built files into `.../sources/openssl/` folder.

I used the following steps from [this instruction](https://github.com/named-data-mobile/NFD-android/blob/master/README.md) to solve it:

```
git clone https://github.com/crystax/android-vendor-openssl.git

cd crystax-ndk-$CRYSTAX_NDK_VERSION

./build/tools/build-target-openssl.sh ../android-vendor-openssl/

cp sources/openssl/1.0.1p/Android.mk sources/openssl/$OPENSSL_VERSION/Android.mk
```